# XML Unicode Identifier / .Net Support

Tags: c#, .net, xml, unicode

I have this xml document:

```
<test />
```

If I load it using this C# code:

```
 var d = new XmlDocument();
 d.LoadXml("<test />");
```

the following exception is thrown:
XmlException: The '' character, hexadecimal value 0x28CD2, cannot be included in a name. Line 1, position 6.

However, the [xml spec reads](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Char):

> NameStartChar      ::=      ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
>
> NameChar     ::=      NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]

"" (which has the code point U+28CD2) clearly falls into the interval [#x10000-#xEFFFF]. Is this a nonconformance of the .Net parser or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be out of luck using the current .Net version.

According to the [documentation for `XmlReader` in .Net 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> XmlReader provides forward-only, read-only access to XML data in adocument or stream. This class conforms to the W3C [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (**fourth edition**)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/) and the [Namespaces in XML 1.0 (third edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) recommendations.

And it appears that in this edition, characters like [yours](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/28cd2/index.htm) outside the [basic multilingual plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) are not valid for element names.  Your character is `0xD863 0xDCD2` in UTF-16, and from the [*Fouth edition* requirements for valid element name characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#NT-NameChar) there are no valid name characters whose code point value is larger than `#xD7A3`.  This is less than the value `#xD800` where [surrogate pair encodings begin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2BD800_to_U.2BDFFF) - and much less than your character `#x28CD2`.

To confirm, from the [wikipedia article on XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#International_use):

> XML 1.0 (**Fifth Edition**) and XML 1.1 support the direct use of almost any Unicode character in element names, attributes, comments, character data, and processing instructions (other than the ones that have special symbolic meaning in XML itself, such as the less-than sign, "<"). The following is a well-formed XML document including Chinese, Armenian and Cyrillic characters:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <俄语 լեզու="ռուսերեն">данные</俄语>
> ```

The framework class that actually throws your exception is `XmlTextReaderImpl`.  Looking through the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextReaderImpl.cs) there are several uses of `#if XML10_FIFTH_EDITION`, [for instance](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextReaderImpl.cs,3915):

```
            unsafe {
#if SILVERLIGHT
                if ( xmlCharType.IsStartNCNameSingleChar( chars[pos] ) ) {
#else // Optimization due to the lack of inlining when a method uses byte*
                if ( ( xmlCharType.charProperties[chars[pos]] & XmlCharType.fNCStartNameSC ) != 0 ) {
#endif
                    pos++;
                }
#if XML10_FIFTH_EDITION
                else if ( pos + 1 < ps.charsUsed && xmlCharType.IsNCNameSurrogateChar(chars[pos + 1], chars[pos])) {
                    pos += 2;
                }
#endif
                else {
                    goto ParseQNameSlow;
                }
            }
```

It appears that if `XML10_FIFTH_EDITION` were defined, XML element names containing surrogate pairs would be supported.  Perhaps Microsoft is planning to enable this in a later version?